# Rounded corners of a QLabel containing a pixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I am trying to display an Image inside a QLabel on QT forms. I need that label to have only the top left and right corners to be rounded while the bottom 2 remain rectangular.

using style sheets I gave the border-radius a value and it worked. Howerver, the image inside that label remained rectangular. (the corner of the image hid the circular corner of the QLabel).

Searching around, i found that setting a mask to the image (pixmap) and drawing a RoundRect on it cause the corners to be circular.

that worked but it made all four corners of the image to be circular.

is there a way to make only the top part as circular?

this is how i made the edges of the pixmap circular:

```
QBitmap map(100,100);     //my pixmap is 100x100
map.fill(Qt::color0);
QPainter painter( &map );
painter.setBrush(Qt::color1);
painter.drawRoundRect(0,0,100,100,20,20);
p.setMask(map);
ui->image1->setPixmap(p);
```

and this is how i made the QLabel top left and right corner circular

```
QString style = "border: 4px solid; \n";
style += "border-top-left-radius: 20px;\n";
style += "border-top-right-radius: 20px;";
ui->image1->setStyleSheet(style);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea with the mask is not too bad. You just have to do some composite drawing to the mask, e.g.

```
QPainter painter(&map);
painter.setBrush(Qt::color1);
painter.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, 100, 40, 20, 20);
painter.drawRect(0, 20, 100, 100);
p.setMask(map);
```

Comment: thx for the reply. i will try that. i did a "Trick" i made the mask rectangle "taller" than the image (drawRoundRect(0,0,100,150,20,20)) so the curved end will be outside the image. it worked but i am not sure if it is a correct way to do it

Comment: The way you did it is also ok. Your code will be easier to maintain if you use map.width() and map.height(), e.g. `painter.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, map.width(), map.height() + 20, 20, 20);`